# How does average profile of person that got accepted into top university look like?

Tags: computer-science, university

I define top university as Harvard, Berkeley, MIT, Stanford, Oxford, Caltech, Yale and similar.

If relevant, I am talking about computer science field.

I am interested in all levels - bachelor, master, phd, post-doc.

Should anything beside: GPA, published papers, supervisor, commercial experience, teaching experience or alma mater ranking be relevant?

How does average profile of person that got accepted into top university look like? What does one need to have to feel reasonably secure about being accepted into top universities?

Comment: The situation for undergraduate admissions will be very different than for graduate, and the former is generally off topic here.  Postdoc is pretty different again, because that's an employee, not a student.

Comment: On the lighter side, your list of "top universities" reminded me of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OKuHYO9TM5A

Comment: For grad school, submit an application that they would strongly consider for a faculty position. In other words, most of what you mentioned doesn't matter.

Comment: For PhD and postdoc, you can just go look up who is currently at these universities. They will often have their CVs online.

Comment: I think this is too broad.

Comment: What is "promotor"? Also, there are many fields where commercial experience doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

> How does average profile of person that got accepted into top university look like?

For reasons mentioned in the comments, I will just briefly address grad school: It's typical to have taken a number of advanced classes (possibly including graduate classes) in your discipline from a good school, and to have done well in them.  You should have strong letters of recommendation.  In some fields (not in math, and I don't think in CS) it's typical to have done some research.  It's pretty common to be international, and straight out of another (bachelors or master's) program.  But I don't know that an "average profile" is the right thing to look at.

> What does one need to have to feel reasonably secure about being accepted into top universities?

You're not in a good position to judge yourself, so talk to your professors.  What kind of schools do they think you should apply to?  What kinds of schools do they think you can get into?  After all, they'll be writing letters for you, which are one of the primary factors in deciding your admissions.

Answer (score -1):

You need recommendations that imply that you are the smartest person the recommender has ever known and sufficient outside evidence to make the recommenders' statements credible.  Generally speaking, unless your recommenders are in positions where they see lots of very smart people, this means you actually have to be very clearly the smartest person your recommenders have ever known.

(This answer isn't true for undergraduate admissions at Berkeley, because it admits so many undergraduates that it cannot actually read individual recommendations carefully.)

Comment: I disagree with your second paragraph. A quick Google shows that Berkeley's 2017 intake was ~15,000, compared to Oxford's measly 3000. Oxford also interviews every candidate they are considering for admission, often more than once.

Comment: @astronat - edited accordingly.

Comment: This is nonsense, based on my experience. Sure, you need a good reference, but being a good fit for the role is much more important than being the "smartest person the recommender has ever known". This answer drastically overstates the elitism of these institutions.